# How to Know the Process Name at Process Exited Event

Tags: vb.net

I run multiple exe with different names by using Process.start() and enables Raisingevents to True. To check the status of Process, I intimated User at Process Exited event and show a message to user.

But the problem is I want to show the particular Exe Name to User at that Exit event. My code for For process Start is:

```
Private Sub StartExe()
Private psi As ProcessStartInfo
Private cmd As Process
Dim filePath As String = "vision.exe"
psi = New ProcessStartInfo(filePath)
Dim systemencoding As System.Text.Encoding = _
        System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.TextInfo.OEMCodePage)
    With psi
        .Arguments = "Some Input String"
        .UseShellExecute = False   
        .RedirectStandardError = True
        .RedirectStandardOutput = True
        .RedirectStandardInput = True
        .CreateNoWindow = False
        .StandardOutputEncoding = systemencoding  
        .StandardErrorEncoding = systemencoding
    End With
    cmd = New Process With {.StartInfo = psi, .EnableRaisingEvents = True}
    AddHandler cmd.ErrorDataReceived, AddressOf Async_Data_Received
    AddHandler cmd.OutputDataReceived, AddressOf Async_Data_Received
    AddHandler cmd.Exited, AddressOf processExited
    cmd.Start()
    cmd.BeginOutputReadLine()
    cmd.BeginErrorReadLine()
  End Sub
  'For Receiving the Output of Exe, I used a TextBox to view
   Private Sub Async_Data_Received(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As   DataReceivedEventArgs)
  Me.Invoke(New InvokeWithString(AddressOf Sync_Output1), e.Data)
  End Sub
   Private Sub Sync_Output1(ByVal text As String)
    txtLog.AppendText(text & Environment.NewLine)
  End Sub
 'At the Exit event, I inform the user that an Exe exited due to some reason etc.
  Private Sub processExited(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
     Me.BeginInvoke(New Action(Function()
     MessageBox.Show("The Stream for " &Particular Exe&   "is Exited.", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)

     End Function))
     End Sub
```

At the Process Exited Event, how can I show name of that particular Exe which fired that event. Like in that particular code, I started an "vision.exe", So I want to inform the user that vision.exe is terminated due to some reason etc.

Answer (score 1):

By the time the Exited event runs, the process is already dead and you cannot retrieve its properties anymore.  Since you already use lambda expressions, you can solve this one too by writing one that captures the *filePath* variable.  Like this:

```
    AddHandler cmd.Exited,
        Sub(s, e)
            Me.BeginInvoke(New Action(
                Sub()
                    MessageBox.Show(filePath + " has ended")
                End Sub))
        End Sub
```

Do beware that you'll have to keep your Form object alive until the process terminates or your own program exits.  If you don't then the BeginInvoke() call is going to be made on a disposed form, also a problem in your original code.  You can avoid this by checking Me.InvokeRequired.  If it returns false then don't do anything.

Comment: I used ur code in exit handler, it gives an error as Filepath is not accessible globally. Global use of FilePath can't meet my requirement. My scenario of FilePath is to access an Exe with different names.I have an Exe for video streaming, a console based Exe which works on different Input strings to perform streaming and conversion. I have a Gridview where User generates Inputstring for that exe. Then I rename Exe with input string name and in Windows task manager, the exe appears with that changed name. So at exit, I want to inform the user that Particular string exited.